# How to expose REST service for JSON?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I need to expose a Spray service that accepts JSON payload. Where can I find a sample that would demonstrate such a feature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I started learning Spray I used [this awesome sample project](https://github.com/jacobus/s4). 
It shows you how to structure your application and much more.

If you want to have a look at how it uses spray-json at the route level, then take a look at [this example](https://github.com/jacobus/s4/blob/master/src/main/scala/s4/rest/S4Service.scala).

Hope it helps! (kudos to Jacobus for S4)